# How to attach existing PVC's to mongodb and postgres deployment using Helm charts?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

I have running PostgreSQL and MongoDB in cluster. Now I want to install new MongoDB and PostgreSQL with existing PVC's created before. How to attach that PVC's to this new installed MongoDB and PostgreSQL using helm? since, I used this command

```bash
helm install my-release bitnami/mongodb --set persistence.existingClaim=mongodb-pv-claim --set volumePermissions.enabled=true
```

for installing one replica. But in my environment, there are 3 mongodb's running with three different PVC's, Now I want to attach those 3 PVC's for newly installing mongo using helm chart. Is there any helm command to attach three PVC's? Note: mongodb(3 replica)